# How to Verify Multiple Foreign Key Combination in a table with a Primary Key in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I Have a Specification Master Table with three columns

```
(
ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar,
Value varchar
)
```

a Product Master Table with two Columns

```
(
ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar
)
```

a Stock table with

```
(
StockID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
ProductID BIGINT FOREIGN KEY (Product.ID),
SpecGroupID BIGINT UNIQUE KEY,
Stock INT
)
```

a Specification Grouping Table with

```
(
GroupID BIGINT FOREIGN KEY (Stock.SpecGroupID),
SPecificationID BIGINT FOREIGN KEY (Specification.ID),
 PRIMARY KEY (Composite)
)
```

Now I am looking for a combination of specification if it has any stock or not.
but could not find a logic to match exact combination.

The problem I am facing if a combination of specification has n specification associated with a stock.SpecGroupID in Specification Grouping Table.
While I am searching with a few less than those n specification combination it always returning the same SpecGroupID for n specs group.

Imagine I have a apple (Color: Red; Size:5; Weight:10) in stock
And someone is ordering for a apple (Color: Red; Size:5)

I Need to give a result: Not Available

Comment: Some sample data will help a lot. In your sample `Apple` is a `Speciffication`?

Comment: Why the result is `Not Available` ?? You have a Red Apple Size 5 in stock. And the order doesnt care about weight.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
SELECT Specification.ID SpecId
, Specification.Name SpecificationName
, Value SpecificationValue
, MAX(ISNULL(Stock.Stock,0)) HasStock
FROM
Specification
LEFT JOIN SpecificationGrouping sg
ON sg.SpecificationID = Specification.ID
LEFT JOIN Stock
ON GroupID = SpecGroupID
GROUP BY Specification.ID 
, Specification.Name 
, Value
```

Answer (score 0):

- First cte `Groups` tell me the specifications of each group.
- Second cte `GroupDetail` join all properties in a single string like this `Color|Red,Size|5,Weight|10`
- Third cte `OrderDetail` is just the test input. in this sample 6 and 9 are orders.
- Last query. Try to find one item on stocks with exact detail as the order

  - If a specification isn't on stocks I assume is an order, here 6 doesn't have item on stock so produce all null and 9 does have stock and return the StockValue.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2d413cb/1)**

```
WITH Groups as 
(
   SELECT *
   FROM SpecificationGrouping SG
   INNER JOIN Specification S
      ON Sg.SPecificationID = S.ID
),
GroupDetail as 
(
    Select distinct ST2.GroupID,
        substring(
        (
            Select ','+ ST1.Name + '|' + ST1.Value  AS [text()]
            From Groups ST1
            Where ST1.GroupID = ST2.GroupID
            ORDER BY ST1.Name
            For XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) [Detail]
    From Groups ST2
),
OrderDetail as 
(
   SELECT Detail
   FROM GroupDetail
   WHERE GroupID = 9
)
 SELECT S.SpecGroupID, S.Stock, G.[Detail]
 FROM Stock S 
 INNER JOIN GroupDetail G
 ON S.SpecGroupID = G.GroupID
 RIGHT JOIN OrderDetail O 
 ON O.Detail = G.Detail
```

**Output for 9**

```
| SpecGroupID | Stock |                     Detail |
|-------------|-------|----------------------------|
|           3 |     5 | Color|Red,Size|5,Weight|10 |
```